# How to add all users and future user identity automatically to enterprise applicaiton?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

Right now I am selecting each user one-by-one to add into my enterprise application. Is there any way so that automatically all the registered user in the tenant gets add and if we add any new user future then it also automatically gets added for enterprise application?

In [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-assign-users) they have mentioned the way for adding user one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [dynamic group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-dynamic-membership) that includes all users in your tenant and add this group to your enterprise application.